# How come the AI makes like 3000 gold per turn on warlord?

Tags: civilization-5

I have 3 times as much in total score, but my GNP is much lower than that of two other civs. How is it possible to make that much money without having the largest population? I am in the renaissance era btw and one of the civs is aiming for a diplomatic victory. This is just ridiculous...[image]

Comment: I believe the answers on [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/123911/how-is-it-possible-to-have-700-gold-income) answer this.  Short answer: Yes, the AI cheats.

Comment: The question says "Warlord", so I don't think that the answer applies.  I don't believe that the AI gets bonuses at Warlord.

Comment: yeah and Rome is allied with like 8 of the 12 state civilizations

Comment: If it's not due to the difficulty bonus, we'll need a good amount of information to diagnose the problem.  At first blush, that's the simplest answer.

Comment: Are you looking at GNP in the demographics screen or gold per turn in the diplomacy screen?

Comment: both, i am far behind them. (i am 3rd)

Comment: they have less cities than me. even my income is far lesser than their gold per turn, which is ridiculous. considering i am no 1 in approval and population. i mean wth?

Comment: More Cities also means more Upkeep cost. Often times having fewer cities can give a significant gold advantage

Comment: but my income is less than their gold per turn. even if we ignore the upkeep, they still make far more than me.

Comment: Do they have religions (or other bonuses) that are generating gold?

Comment: they somehow generated tons of gold when i started giving money to city-states. i reloaded the game without doing that and they didnt generate as much gold.

Answer (score 0):

The AI gets bonuses and the player gets handicaps based on the difficulty level. The AI gets a lot of bonuses which make things cheaper.

There's a handy table [here](http://www.civfanatics.com/civ5/difficulties), on the Civ Fanatics forums, of the exact figures. As an example, on the highest difficulty, their units cost 50% less (though on Warlord their unit costs are 100%)